# Put apostrophe in alert message

Tags: c#, asp.net, alert, message, apostrophe

I found out how to show an error message in the catch{} and it works like charm.
But the app is french and I need to add an apostrophe (') in the message and it can't do it. I tried double apostrophe (''), the inverted slash before apostrophe (\'), the apostrophe in quotes ("''") and they don't work.

Here's the code for my error message.

```
catch
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
        this, 
        this.GetType(), 
        "alertMessage", 
        "alert('Erreur lors de l'enregistrement de la demande.')", true);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should be able to use a escape for this. Since you're calling it from the code behind a  double escape:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Erreur lors de l\\'enregistrement de la demande.')", true);
```

to add a line break in the script a line escape should be added with a double escape:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Erreur lors de l\\'enregistrement de la demande.\\nLinebreak shizzle.')", true);
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works! I didn't thought of putting two slashes.
Also, do you know how to add the action of <br /> in the message? It only shows as text.

Comment: Also works, thanks! I know these are REEEAAAL basic questions but I just happened of not knowing the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
    this, 
    this.GetType(), 
    "alertMessage", 
    "alert(""Erreur lors de l'enregistrement de la demande."")", 
    true
)
```

Comment: I think you need to use a verbatim string if you want to use double double-quotes like this. @"alert(""Erreur lors de l'enregistrement de la demande."")"